# Using slices in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, slice, prediction

I use the dataset from UCI repo: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Energy+efficiency
Then doing next:

```
from pandas import *
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

dataset = read_excel('/Users/Half_Pint_boy/Desktop/ENB2012_data.xlsx')
dataset = dataset.drop(['X1','X4'], axis=1)
trg = dataset[['Y1','Y2']]
trn = dataset.drop(['Y1','Y2'], axis=1)
```

Then do the models and cross validate:

```
models = [LinearRegression(), 
      RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, max_features ='sqrt'), 
      KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=6),
      SVR(kernel='linear'), 
      LogisticRegression() 
     ]
Xtrn, Xtest, Ytrn, Ytest = train_test_split(trn, trg, test_size=0.4)
```

I'm creating a regression model for predicting values but have a problems. Here is the code:

```
TestModels = DataFrame()
tmp = {}

for model in models:

    m = str(model)
    tmp['Model'] = m[:m.index('(')]    

for i in range(Ytrn.shape[1]):
    model.fit(Xtrn, Ytrn[:,i]) 
    tmp[str(i+1)] = r2_score(Ytest[:,0], model.predict(Xtest))
    TestModels = TestModels.append([tmp])
    TestModels.set_index('Model', inplace=True)
```

It shows unhashable type: 'slice' for line model.fit(Xtrn, Ytrn[:,i])

How can it be avoided and made working?

Thanks!

Comment: try to change `model.fit(Xtrn, Ytrn[:,i]) ` to `model.fit(Xtrn, Ytrn[:i])`, remove comma

Comment: please post the entire traceback and/or post complete runnable code so I can get the traceback myself.

Comment: I can reproduce the error message `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'` if `Ytrn` is a DataFrame. In that case, you need to use `Ytrn.iloc[:, i]` instead of `Ytrn[:, i]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/34215501/190597.

Comment: thanks, iloc works. but then it goes: Unknown label type: array([ 29.9 ,  26.84,  28.07,  39.89,  14.32,  11.33,  15.55,  10.39]). Is it because 2-d array?

Comment: That look like a 1D array. Please post a runnable example which generates the error so we don't have to guess.

Comment: I tries to write a full code, maybe it will help

Comment: Are Xtrn and Ytrn pandas dataframe?

Comment: yes, they are frames

Comment: Did you try converting them to numpy arrays before fitting your data to sklearn?

Comment: doesnt work sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I had a similar problem before! Try to convert your data to numpy arrays before feeding them to `sklearn` estimators. It most probably solve the hashing problem. For instance, You can do:

```
Xtrn_array = Xtrn.as_matrix() 
Ytrn_array = Ytrn.as_matrix()
```

and use Xtrn_array and Ytrn_array when you fit your data to estimators.