# Python: Is it OK to use "as_matrix" with dataframes as input to scikit models

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

Hi I have seen some examples of machine learning implementations that uses as_matrix with dataframes as inputs to machine learning algorithms. I wonder if it is OK to use tuples, which are output of .as_matrix as inputs to machine learning algorithms such as below. Thanks

```
trainArr_All = df.as_matrix(cols_attr)  # training array
trainRes_All = df.as_matrix(col_class)  # training results
trainArr, x_test, trainRes, y_test = train_test_split(trainArr_All, trainRes_All, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20, criterion='gini', random_state=42)  # 100 decision trees
y_score = rf.fit(trainArr, trainRes.ravel()).predict(x_test)
y_score = y_score.tolist()
```

Comment: Tuples are *not* the output... The output is a `numpy.ndarray`. I don't really see this method very often, and generally I would use `df.values` which achieves the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `as_matrix` converts the dataframe to **numpy.array** ([documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html)) **NOT tuple**! sklearn assumes that the inputs are in the form of numpy arrays and if not it converts the dtype to dtype=np.float32 or a sparse csc_matrix internally. Although using pandas dataframe as input is usually fine when using a stable version of sklearn (internal conversion), you may have occasional problems due to data type incompatibility. It is usually safer to use `as_matrix` and convert the dataframe to numpy.array before using sklearn.

Here is an example of someone having problem with pandas dataframe:
[Using slices in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211339/using-slices-in-python/39234260#39234260)